# Suggest + gerund or not that is the question

Tags: grammar, infinitive-vs-gerund

As I understand the B1/B2 grammar book by Raymond Murphy, the 19 verbs (I know this list by heart now)

> enjoy, mind, suggest, stop, postpone, admit, avoid, deny, fancy, risk, imagine, consider, finish, keep, keep on, put off, give up, go on, carry on

are supposed to be followed by a gerund.

For example:

I'll do the shopping when I've finished cleaning the flat.
/ He suggested going to the cinema.

---

Then why do they say,

> "I suggest you choose these glasses."

instead of "I suggest you choosing these glasses?"

Even the application "Grammarly" doesn't consider "choosing" as a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest (your) choosing a game instead of a movie=I suggest you choose a game.

Suggest is followed **by a gerund or by an independent clause.** It is like recommend and advise.

What that list of verbs means to avoid is this:

I suggest to go to a movie. instead of: I suggest we go or I suggest going to a movie. or things like: I enjoy to go to a movie. Instead of: I enjoy going to the movies.

The other ones in the list can only take a gerund: enjoy playing tennis; mind opening the window;fancy  having a drink;finish doing the work, etc. ( I don't particularly fancy writing examples for every single one.)

**suggest is part of a category of verbs that can take a gerund or an independent clause (I hope I got them all), unlike the others on that list**.

- I suggest we leave now. I suggest leaving now.
- I advise leaving now. I advise we leave now.
- He recommends finishing early. He recommends we finish early.
- They advised publishing the book. They advised we publish the book.
- We denied damaging the car. We denied we damaged the car.

These verbs that can go both ways as shown above are: suggest, recommend, advise, deny.

careful with imagine: I imagine we left at six o'clock. [think] I imagined we left at six o'clock. [it was something in my imagination]

Sometimes verbs are in two categories and sometimes only in one in terms of how they can be used.

Comment: OK so if I understand the premises, this is your choice, then you choose => I suggest you choose (meaning I let you make the choice). However, if that is my recommendation I would rather say "I suggest choosing this game rather than this one". (It's still your choice but in this sentence, I emphasise on "I suggest", so I am the subject of the sentence and then my whole action is "suggest choosing"? It's probably a bit confused like I say it but I think I get the idea?

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C You have not understood me, I think. I am telling you that suggest, recommend and advise can take an independent clause. The other verbs in the list cannot. And I have given clear examples. I suggest you choose this game=I suggest (your) choosing this game. The two carry the same exact meaning.

Comment: OK then I do not understand what does "choosing" mean in the sentence "I suggest your choosing this game". Is that a noun derivated from to choose and having the same meaning as "choice"?

Comment: Ah, so many games to choose from, Henry. What shall I buy my granddaughter? Well, John, I suggest choosing a good one. = I suggest you choose a good one. Choosing is from the verb choose. It is a noun formed from a gerund.

Comment: Then I understand! :D

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *I suggest you choosing these glasses.*
>
> [2] *I suggest you choose these glasses.*

The simple answer is that these have similar meanings, but the complementation is different.

In the first, "suggest" is a catenative verb that takes non-finite gerund-participial clauses as complement. Here we normally find genitive subjects: "I suggest your choosing these glasses".

[2] is in competition with [1], but instead of being a catenative verb with a non-finite clause as complement, "suggest" is non-catenative with the declarative content clause "you choose these glasses" as complement. The clause is just as much subordinate (dependent) as that in [1], but it is finite as opposed to non-finite.